# StructureMap : container.WhatDoIHave() shows same class twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, startup, structuremap, scanning

I've the following interface:

```
public interface IOneWayMapper<in TSource, out TDestination>
{
    TDestination Map(TSource source);
}
```

And the following class:

```
public class ProfileMapper : IOneWayMapper<Profile1, Profile2>
{
    public Profile2 Map(Profile1 source)
    {
        return new Profile2();
    }
}
```

And this interface is registered in the scanner like:

```
scanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IOneWayMapper<,>));
```

When calling `container.WhatDoIHave()`, I get this output:

```
  StructureMap : WhatDoIHave()        
  ========================================================================================
  PluginType         Namespace      Lifecycle     Description                Name       
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ProfileMapper      Mappers        Transient     Mappers.ProfileMapper     (Default)   
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ProfileMapper      Mappers        Transient     Mappers.ProfileMapper     (Default)
```

**Question**
Is this an issue ? If yes, how to solve?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/7815105/5233410

Comment: Most likely you are registering it twice but since you are not showing the complete registration code it is impossible to tell. Hence the reason a [mcve] was requested.